# Filter database not to display same data

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access

How will I filter this Access DB:
[image]
To make it look like this in `ComboBox1`
[image]
Also, I am using a comboBox to display field datas, I only use `use data bound items` it its properties so eventually it will display ALL of data that it can see, but I only want each of the same data in that field. I am not coding it, but either way will do fine. Thanks
**UPDATE:** 
Sample Code that I want:

```
Dim update() = FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.Select("Each of the Same data name")
comboBox1.Items.Add(update)
' don't know if something like this will work.
```

That code is referenced from this one: (*which is working*) - this gets the value of "DVRIP" from a data in "ButtonText" field.

```
Dim host = FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.Select("ButtonText =" & "'" & sender.Text & "'")(0)("DVRIP")
' SELECT DVRIP WHERE ButtonText = CAMERA01 ~ I think its like this in SQL
```

Comment: Instead of binding the datasource directly to the combobox, can't you create a new IList from the datasource and apply filtering to this list before you bind it to your combobox ?

Comment: If its what you think have a better chance, spit it out. As I have said, either way is okay, I just want to know how :)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the source object with your datasource. Here's a sample console app that should suffice.

```
    Module Module1

        Sub Main()

            Dim source As New List(Of MyDataItems)()
            source.Add(New MyDataItems() With { _
      .DataValue = "CSI", _
      .DisplayText = "CSI" _
     })
            source.Add(New MyDataItems() With { _
      .DataValue = "CSI", _
      .DisplayText = "CSI" _
     })
            source.Add(New MyDataItems() With { _
      .DataValue = "Mall", _
      .DisplayText = "Mall" _
     })
            source.Add(New MyDataItems() With { _
      .DataValue = "Mall", _
      .DisplayText = "Mall" _
     })
            source.Add(New MyDataItems() With { _
      .DataValue = "House", _
      .DisplayText = "House" _
     })
            source.Add(New MyDataItems() With { _
      .DataValue = "House", _
      .DisplayText = "House" _
     })
            Console.WriteLine("Initial List items  contents")
            source.ForEach(Sub(m As MyDataItems) Console.WriteLine(m.DataValue))
            Console.WriteLine("List items after applying Filter")
            Dim distinctItems = source.GroupBy(Function(x) x.DisplayText).[Select](Function(y) y.First()).ToList
            distinctItems.ForEach(Sub(m As MyDataItems) Console.WriteLine(m.DataValue))
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub

    End Module
```

Comment: That's a lot of work if you would even code all the data in the field which you don't have to do and will not be able to do if the data are user created.

Comment: Definitely it is, but Leis seemed to be expecting a detailed answer. Actually, the answer lies in just 1 line: 

*source.GroupBy(Function(x) x.DisplayText).[Select](Function(y) y.First()).ToList*

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT Building
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Building;
```

Comment: Got an exception on this line: `Dim update() = FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.Select("Building FROM tblCamButtons GROUP BY Building")` ~ `Missing operand after 'FROM' operator`

Comment: @AdorableVB You're doing it wrong. You didn't include the SELECT clause, which makes your SQL statement wrong. SQL Statement should be "SELECT Building
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Building".

Comment: Check again, `.Select("string")` that's the Select clause. I can't use it like Select SELECT right?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm actually not familiar with the object you are using. You are using VB.NET on winforms, wpf? Or is that macro for access? I'm not entirely sure how to use that object and its properties and methods. Could you explain a bit more where you got that?

Comment: I use VB.net, Check updated question, hope you can get some insight on how I made use of the `SELECT` clause to vb (*code from SO people*)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim dt As DataTable = camButtonDtable.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Building")
comboBox1.DataValue = "Building"
comboBox1.DisplayText = "Building"
comboBox1.DataBind()
```